# Sequelize (Nestjs) error connection Postgresql 8.4

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, pg

I have problem to connect in Postgres 8.4 version with Sequelize. Show me an error about not exist 'pg_range' (error message: `relation "pg_range" dows not exist`).

When I try connect in Postgre 9 it works. How can I connect in Postgres 8.4?

**Technologies what I'm using:**

1. Postgresql v8.4
2. @nestjs/core v7.5.1
3. @nestjs/sequelize v0.2.0
4. sequelize-typescript v0.2.0
5. sequelize v6.5.0
6. pg (Non-blocking PostgreSQL client) v8.5.1

**Error:**

```
[Nest] 22866   - 03/26/2021, 3:42:41 AM   [SequelizeModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +85ms
error: no existe la relación «pg_range»
    at Connection.parseE (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:567:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:391:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're version of PostgreSQL is [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/catalog-pg-range.html) by your JS client.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, it is indicated the version of pg since pg_range exists (9.2)
[enter link description here](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_range.html)