# I need to conect with an postgres 8 with node and sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, node-postgres, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to connect to an PostgreSQL 8 and sequelize is printing an error that references pg_range,
i think that's something that disable pg_range use on pg library for node

tried this:

my code:

````js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import 'dotenv/config';

export default new Sequelize(
  process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME,
  process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    schema: process.env.POSTGRES_SCHEMA,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    standardConformingStrings: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      disableRange: true,
      requestTimeout: 100, // tried something to solve but with no success
    },
  },
);```

the error :
Unable to connect to the database: error: relation "pg_range" does not exist
````

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66812213/sequelize-nestjs-error-connection-postgresql-8-4. Postgres 8.4 has gone out of support 10 years ago and it is normal you cannot connect to it using recent libraries. Urgently upgrade your DB.

Comment: Too many problems, waist of time, don’t even try. Spend your time on upgrading to a recent and supported version